# Why do we have to use int a[][10] when passing 2d arrays to functions?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I want to pass a 2d array to a function, and I know how to do it

```
int function(int a[][10])
```

The problem is, I dont like working with stuff I dont understand, so I would like to understand why do we have to use "int a[][10]" instead of "int a[10][10]".

Comment: Yup its decay in action. The answer says it all, if 'a' presents some concept in code I also often use the solution where I create a struct with a meaningful name and just add the array as member. That way you also limit your function to only work on an abstraction instead of a type.

Comment: For the same reason that you have to use `int function(int a[])` when you pass a 1d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** the function parameter `a` is a pointer to an array of size 10 having elements of type `int`. That is, the parameter `a` is **not an array** as you might be thinking.

This is called **type decay** as quoted below:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

You asked

> why do we have to use "int a[][10]" instead of "int a[10][10]".

It doesn't matter if you use `int a[][10]` or `int a[10][10]` because in both cases the parameter `a` is a pointer to an array of size 10 having elements of type `int`.

If you want to pass a 1D array of `int` elements you can use templates as shown below in version 1:

**Version 1**: Pass 1D array by reference

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
int function(int (&a)[N])// a is a reference to a 1D array of size N having elements of type int
{
    return 5; //return something according to your needs
}

int main()
{
    int arr[3] = {0};
    function(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

**Version 2**: Pass a 2D array by reference

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N, int M>
int function(int (&a)[N][M])// a is a reference to a 2D array
{
    return 5; //return something according to your needs
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10][10];
    function(arr);
    return 0;
}
```